# How Do I pass the list value for paginate to render properly?

Tags: grails, groovy, pagination

I want to display all the `project`'s `tasks` in a page, given that the user can have many `projects`. In such a case, a user will select any one `project` from the drop-down list box and I find that project instance using :

```
    def proj = params.managersProject // this is the choice made by the manager 
    def project = Project.findByName("$proj")
```

Now I have all the details in `project` instance. Now I need to display the `tasks` of that particular project. Since it have so many `tasks`, I need to paginate it. But for paginating to work properly, I guess we need to pass the `params` like this :

```
Project.list(params) // which will be passed on to the views for rendering.
```

But in my case, I couldn't able to call that `list()` method on `project` instance, that I got earlier. How do I solve this?

### Edit:

After got answer from [tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262684/how-do-i-pass-the-list-value-for-paginate-to-render-properly/9263006#9263006), I tried this:

```
 def tasks = Tasks.findAllByProject( project, params )
    def size = tasks.size()
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10,100)
    return [tasksInstanceList: Tasks.findAllByProject(project,params), tasksInstanceTotal: size]
```

This returns the result, but when I click on the `next` button I don't see any table being rendered. After that when I click on `prev` button, I couldn't see anything. I clearly know that there is some problem with `tasksInstanceList`, I'm not sure whether the `params` is passing into it or not. But when I click on `prev` and `next` button I can clearly see my browsers add changing from :

```
http://localhost:8080/app/controller?offset=0&max=10
```

to:

```
http://localhost:8080/app/controller?offset=10&max=10
```

In view file I have this code:

```
<g:paginate total="${tasksInstanceTotal}"/>
```

Since I'm very new to grails, I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be the perfect expert on pagination (I typically trip a bit over it myself) but if its the project's Tasks hasmany property you're trying to paginate through, Project.list() probably isn't what you want.

If your params has a .max and .offset (as in, you're using the < g:paginate > tag and you provided it with a task listing controller action), what I typically do is use a criteriaBuilder with the somewhat-obscured PagedResultList return type. I'm guessing there's a better way to go about it, but something like

```
def yourProjectInstance = Project.get(params.yourProjectId)
def taskPagedResult = Task.createCriteria().list(max: params.max as Integer, offset: params.offset as Integer) {
  eq('project', yourProjectInstance)
  //optionally, if you're using sortableColumn here as well, you can do
  //order(params.sort, params.order)
}

render view: 'taskPagedTable', model: [taskList: taskPagedResult, taskCount: taskPagedResult.totalCount()]
```

Should put a list of params.max Tasks in your view's taskList, but still give you the total number of tasks for that project in the taskCount variable.

Hope that helps!

Reference: http://blog.jeffshurts.com/2010/04/grails-pagination-and-criteriabuilder/

**EDIT:**

My guess is that what's missing here is the *action* attribute for your paginate tag, especially if hitting the URL precisely is producing the proper results for you.
You need to point your paginate tag at whatever controller action has your code block.

One other thing I can think of looking at your controller code is your size variable might be misleading; it's going to be the same as whatever *params.max* was. This is where the PagedResultList portion of my answer comes into play. Either that, or you could have size be equal to

```
def size = Tasks.countByProject(project)
```

That way your g:paginate tag's *total* property will be accurate.

Comment: Kind of a different question now but I will edit my answer to help :)

Comment: oh man! My head is rolling. I just used your code `taskPagedResult`. But still getting the same problem!!! I printed the `taskPagedResult` value on my console and noted that, when I click next button its not rendering the results, I get only empty array!

Comment: But I didn't specify the params max and offset value any where! :( kindly help me.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of your project source? I'm not sure how else to explain it

Comment: I got the output. It was, my `params.managersProject` was lost when I was clicking on my `next` button! I restored it and now it works :)

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out :) I've had issue with that (losing search params on roundtrip) as well, probably some kind of CommandObject pattern would help facilitate that process, or use of the *flash* variable. Try those to see if it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Can you use:

```
def proj = params.managersProject // this is the choice made by the manager 
def project = Project.findByName("$proj")
def tasks = Task.findByProject( project, params )
```

Where the `max` and `offset` are [in the params map](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#finders)?

Comment: No I actually set via this code : `params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 15,100)`. But I didn't show it in my question.

Comment: Nevertheless, Ant's, wherever your max and offset are, passing them in a map as Tim passed them to .findByProject is the simplest way to handle this (much simpler than my way). If you find your discrimination criteria to get complicated enough where you need a criteriaBuilder, my answer might prove useful, but Tim has the more correct response :)

Comment: @tim_yates: this works. But I'm confused with `offset` and `max` concepts. Notably I used the list page of the `Tasks` class that is generated via scaffolding as my view file of this controller action, my making slight changes. But that leads to half an output! Meant that prev and next button are not working, paginating is not happening properly! How do I overcome this?

Comment: You're going to have to put a better description of the problem than that in the question or something...  What values of `max` and `offset` are you sending through?  What does _"...half an output"_ look like?